# Symfony 4: как вывести шаблон на главной?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

Ввел в терминале:

```
$ php bin/console make:controller DefaultController
```

Указал в контроллере:

```
// ...
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     */
    public function new(Request $request)
    {

        // ...
        return $this->render('default/new.html.twig', [
            'default' => $default->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Теперь вместо: *"Welcome to Symfony 4.3.1. Your application is now ready..."* (`base.html.twig`). Выводится шаблон `new.html.twig`.

**Вопрос:** я вывел сформированный DefaultController шаблон `new.html.twig` на главной. Правильно ли я его вывел? Нужно было использовать `base.html.twig` указанным ниже образом? `index.php` не трогать? Может когда-нибудь потребоваться не использовать routing, а просто создать страницу? Например: `/public/page.php`

```
// ...
  /**
   * @Route("/")
   */
  public function new(Request $request)
  {
    // ...
    return $this->render('base.html.twig', [
        'default' => $default->createView(),
    ]);
  }
// ...
```

Comment: Наилучшим способом является расширение базового шаблона. Вы создаете шаблон например `base.html.twig` подключаете в него необходимые стили, скрипты и всё что вы будете использовать глобально. Затем наследуете этот шаблон вашим `index.html.twig` и указываете его в контроллере .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы понять использовать  или не использовать `base.html.twig`, нужно немного понять идею шаблонизатора twig, да и вообще шаблонизаторов. Его базовые элементы - это блоки. Блоки могут наследоваться/перезависываться. В результате у Вас получиться некая иерархия шаблонов, где, возможно, самый главный шаблон будет `base.html.twig` какой-нибудь дочерний `categories.html.twig` и дочерний дочернего `new.html.twig`.

**Выделяем общее**. Как написал [@AntonKucenko](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/266145/anton-kucenko), в базовый контроллер вы можете подключить скрипты, стили, определить общие блоки страницы: хедер, футер, задать блок контента и меню:

В результате чего базовый шаблон будет иметь вид

*base.html.twig*

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title>{{ title }}</title>

      {% block stylesheets %}
           <link href="{{ asset('css/base.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
        {% endblock %}
  </head>

  <body>
    {% block header %}
       <div>Верстка общего хидера</div>
    {% endblock %}

    {% block menu %}
      верстка меню
    {% endblock %}

    {% block content %}{% endblock %}

    {% block footer %}
       <div>Верстка общего футера</div>
    {% endblock %}

    {% block javascripts %}
        <script src="{{ asset('js/base.js') }}"></script>
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Допустим `DefaultController` это домашняя страница, у которой есть свой блок контента, свои стили + стили базового шаблона (хедер футер ...) и свой фронт + базовый. Тогда `new.html.twig` будет выглядеть так.

*new.html.twig*

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

 {% block stylesheets %}
     {{ parent() }}
      <link href="{{ asset('css/new.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
 {% endblock %}

 {% block javascripts %}
     {{ parent() }}
      <script src="{{ asset('js/new.js') }}"></script>
 {% endblock %}

 {% block content %}
     <div>разметка контента</div>
 {% endblock %}
```

Теперь в `base.html.twig` "вставлятся" блоки из `new.twig.html`, и все это выведется на экран.

Плюсом есть и то, что блоки в дочерних шаблонах можно описывать в любом порядке, а также можно совмещать родительские блоки и дочерние используя метод `parent`.